# How to measure connectivity using Tarjan's algorithm in Apache Age to measure connectivity

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I have been trying to implement Tarjan's algorithm to measure strongly connected components in a graph Can anyone provide guidance on how to implement Tarjan's algorithm in Apache-Age to measure connectivity between nodes since I could not find anything yet?
Here is the code in python

```
index = 0
stack = []
ids = {}
lowlink = {}
onStack = {}
result = []

def tarjan(current_node):
    global index
    ids[current_node] = index
    lowlink[current_node] = index
    index += 1
    stack.append(current_node)
    onStack[current_node] = True

    for neighbor in current_node.get_neighbors():
        if neighbor not in ids:
            tarjan(neighbor)
            lowlink[current_node] = min(lowlink[current_node], lowlink[neighbor])
        elif onStack[neighbor]:
            lowlink[current_node] = min(lowlink[current_node], ids[neighbor])

    if ids[current_node] == lowlink[current_node]:
        connected_component = []
        while True:
            neighbor = stack.pop()
            onStack[neighbor] = False
            connected_component.append(neighbor)
            if neighbor == current_node:
                break
        result.append(connected_component)
```

how to I implement this code using apache age to measure connectivity?

Answer (score 1):

Try following these steps

- Use a PostgreSQL database connector in    python to connect to the
  database running AGE.
- Use a Cypher query to retrieve the graph to analyze. The query should
  return the nodes and relationships in the graph.
- Use the results of the Cypher query to    build an in-memory
  representation of the graph that you can use as    the input to your
  implementation of Tarjan's algorithm. You might    represent the
  graph as an adjacency list or adjacency matrix,    depending on
  what's most convenient for your implementation of the    algorithm.
- Run your implementation of Tarjan's algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following steps to measure the connectivity using tarjan's algorithm:

- First, create a graph in AGE using TinkerPop API.
- Now make your tarjan's algorithm in python to use the TinkerPop API for graph traversing.
- After this, you can use tarjan's algorithm to find the strongly connected components.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following steps to implement the Tarjan's algorithm for accurately taking measurements for strongly connected components when using Apache AGE:

1. Ensure that Apache AGE is installed and Apache Cassandra is also up and running with it alongside.
2. Instantiate a graph schema and upload the relevant tada into the graph.
3. The python code that is generated will be translated into AGE query language.